# WAMp mysql service error : Wamp not turning MYSQL services on

Tags: mysql, wamp

Situation :

1) My WAMP suddenly not turning green.
2) I found that my MYSQL service is generating this error :

**#2002 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).**

3) Then i got a solution to **DELETE iblogfile0 , 1 and ibdata1 I tried and it worked !**

4) then when i looked MySQL database my most of tables wasn't working at all they generate error  **table doesn't exist !**

---

Now what should I do ? ( I have old iblog files safe )

Comment: Deleteing `ibdata1` deleted the file that contains all your data. Whereever you found that ___?fix?___ you had better thank them for that

Comment: Replace the files. Start WAMPServer **and then read the MySQL Error log** The error should be described in there. Or if not then look in the Windows Event Log for message from MySQL. _You cannot fix an issue until you understand what the issue is_

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error with mysql, i solved this way: search whether some mysql-bin.* files be in data folder, delete it and try again